# Multiple Rich Text Fields on same XPage

Tags: xpages, richtextbox

I have an XPage with three Rich Text Fields on it. When the page is in Read Mode the content is separated and shows each field distinctly. However, when the page is put in Edit Mode the three RT Fields get consolidated into what looks like one control containing the three RTFs. I see how it is working and if you enter stuff at the correct locations it works correctly but is very confusing. Is there a way to force each RTF to be represented separately? And if there are other controls between the RTF Controls it really gets confusing because these input controls look like they are contained in the Rich Text Control. Very messy. Can't see a property on the RTF that would fix this.

Comment: I have almost 10 RTF on my XPage but works precisely well, can you please share some code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had set the height of the RT Control in Pixels and in the layout they overlapped. I changed the height to Auto and now they display correctly with no overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of your RTF controls if they point to the same field in the document. I got that as a what I call "copy & paste" error.

Comment: That is not the issue in this case. Copy and paste can save a lot of time or create a lot of trouble.

Comment: Can you please show some source code of your XPage to get an idea?